# JMC flight recorder not showing custom methods

Tags: java, jmc, jfr

This is my first time with Flight recorder. Tried to start a flight recording against my app code which has the flags set `-XX:+UnlockCommercialFeatures -XX:+FlightRecorder`.

However when I open the recorded file, it would seem that only core java packages are shown under hot methods/packages. And absolutely none of my own code/package shows up. Any suggestions ?

[image]

Comment: My Bad. As @kire-haglin pointed out, was looking at the wrong recording,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the filename (flight_recording_180101TheJVMRunnningJavaMissioControl_2.jfr), it looks like you are making a recording against Java Mission Control, not the application you are running.